# Cooperative game vs Multiplayer game

Tags: terminology

Can any one tell what is difference between cooperative game and multiplayer game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiplayer games simply have multiple players playing the same game at the same time.  Usually in our day and age, "online" is assumed when one mentions multiplayer, although [this is not always the case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotseat_(multiplayer_mode)).

[Cooperative games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_gameplay) typically feature multiplayer elements, but are typically focused on a subset of multiplayer games where the overall goal is to work together, usually against a non-human opponent.

Comment: So it is not necessary that multiplayer game to be cooperative ? or can we say, Cooperative game is a kind of subset of Multiplayer games? i.e. Multiplayer games can be either coorperative or non cooperative, whereas Cooperative game can only be multiplayer.

Comment: @rohit, I'd say in general that's a safe assumption to make.  If a game advertises "online multiplayer" they're *usually* talking about humans vs. humans, and "co-op gameplay" *usually* means humans vs AI.  If you're looking at a particular game, I highly suggest looking it up on [Co-Optimus](http://www.co-optimus.com/) which will list all multiplayer and co-op modes (online and off) that a game supports on each platform.

Comment: @rohit The "non cooperative" multiplayer is usually referred to as competitive multiplayer.

Answer (score -2):

Coop is usually split screen where two or more people are playing on the same device and multiplayer is gaming online with people around the world similar to Xbox Live